# Imputation of categorical variables in python/scikit

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a csv file with 23 columns of categorical string variables i.e. Gender, Location, skillset, etc.

Several of these columns have missing values. No column is missing more than 20% of its data so I would like to impute the missing categorical variables.

is this possible?

I have tried 
    from sklearn_pandas import CategoricalImputer

```
imputer=CategoricalImputer(strategy='most_frequent', axis=1)
imputer.fit(df[["Permission", "Hope"]])
imputer.transform(df)
```

but I am getting this error:
    NameError: name 'categoricalImputer' is not defined

Will I have to Hotcode each of the 23 columns to intergers before I can impute?
or is it possible to impute missing categorical string variables?

Comment: just open python in the console and then type sklearn.__version__

Comment: you should update to version 0.20. Here is just run `pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git` or check this https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10579

Answer (score 2):

`CategoricalImputer` is only introduced in version `0.20`. So update with `pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git` or check the github issue https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10579